# How to deal with Quarkus OIDC cookie expiration and Ajax requests CORS failure?

Tags: ajax, jsf, xmlhttprequest, keycloak, quarkus-oidc

I have a Quarkus + Primefaces (server side rendered) web app which is using Quarkus OIDC integration.
Configured like this:

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=${oidc_serverUrl}
quarkus.oidc.client-id=my-jsf-app
quarkus.oidc.application-type=web-app
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=${oidc_secret}
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.paths=/secure/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.policy=authenticated
quarkus.oidc.authentication.cookie-same-site=lax
quarkus.oidc.tls.verification=none
# Only the authenticated users can initiate a logout:
quarkus.oidc.logout.path=/secure/logout
# Logged-out users should be returned to the /welcome.html site which will offer an option to re-login:
quarkus.oidc.logout.post-logout-path=/secure/user/home.xhtml
quarkus.oidc.token-state-manager.split-tokens=true
quarkus.oidc.token-state-manager.strategy=id-refresh-tokens
quarkus.oidc.authentication.cookie-path=/secure/
```

After the q_session and q_session_rt cookies expire on the browser side and the first Ajax request is redirected to OIDC endpoint for re-authentication. Browser console logs this:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://keycloak.myapp.com/auth/realms/my-app/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=my-jsf-app&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.myapp.com%2Fsecure%2Fuser%2FaccountWizard.xhtml&state=b8afe3c2-0302-4592-a2b4-ad67997fad32' (redirected from 'https://dev.myapp.com/secure/user/accountWizard.xhtml?jfwid=cc9f2') from origin 'https://dev.myapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

After Ajax request fails - all ordinary GET/POST requests start to fail with 401 as well. When in this state, forced page reload also doesn't work (the browser shows 'This page doesn't work' + 401 status code). Quarkus app log shows this:

```
2023-06-10 21:49:22,257 DEBUG [io.qua.oid.run.CodeAuthenticationMechanism] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) State parameter can not be empty or multi-valued if the state cookie is present
```

In order to continue, user have to clean the browser cache.

I added the correct URL to the Keycloak Web origins, but it still fails when Ajax request is redirected to Keycloak. How to fix it?

Cross-referencing https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/20910

Comment: as mentioned on the mailing list I believe you need to open a GitHub Issue ticket for the specific issue mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak Authorization endpoint does not support cross-origin redirects made with XHR, therefore the script has to handle such redirects as described in

https://quarkus.io/guides/security-oidc-code-flow-authentication-concept#single-page-applications